# Check if we can travel from source to destination

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem Statement**

In Takahashi Kingdom, there is an archipelago of N islands, called Takahashi Islands. For convenience, we will call them Island 1, Island 2, ..., Island N.

There are M kinds of regular boat services between these islands. Each service connects two islands. The i-th service connects Island ai and Island bi.

Cat Snuke is on Island 1 now, and wants to go to Island N. However, it turned out that there is no direct boat service from Island 1 to Island N, so he wants to know whether it is possible to go to Island N by using two boat services.

If it is possible to go to Island N by using two boat services, print POSSIBLE; otherwise, print IMPOSSIBLE.

[image]

**Example:**

```
N = 3
First boat services : 1 2
Second boat services: 2 3
```

**Output:**
POSSIBLE

**Explanation:**
Using first boat, I can start from source point 1, and go to 2. Now using second boat I can go from 2 to 3, here 3 is my destination.

I am trying to understand what is the approach we need to follow to solve this problem?

I tried this basic approach, which will work for this test case, but I know that i am going in wrong way.

```
public static String check(List<Integer> boat1, List<Integer> boat2, int N) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> first = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < boat1.size() - 1; i++) {
            first.put(boat1.get(i), boat1.get(i + 1));
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> second = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < boat2.size() - 1; i++) {
            second.put(boat2.get(i), boat2.get(i + 1));
        }

        if (first.get(1) != null) {
            int island = first.get(1);
            if (second.get(island) != null) {
                island = second.get(island);
                if (island == N) {
                    return "POSSIBLE";
                }
            }
        }
        return "Impossible";
    }
```

**Update:**

Lets say boat 1 services are 1, 2, 3, 4 and boat 2 services are 3,5.
Trying with Josep answer now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GrafDirLlistes s = new GrafDirLlistes(5);
    s.afegirAresta(1, 2, 1);
    s.afegirAresta(2, 3, 1);
    s.afegirAresta(3, 4, 1);
    s.afegirAresta(3, 5, 1);
    s.dfs();
    System.out.println(s.existeixAresta(1, 5));

}
```

I am expecting true for above program as we can travel from 1 to 5 like this 1->2->3->5, but the program is returning false.

Comment: you may want to write a function that checks if you can get from island a to island b.

Comment: The problem isn't very well stated.  Does "connect 1 and 2" mean that the service goes only in one direction 1 --> 2? Or does it also mean 2 -->1?

Comment: @Gene, this is the whole problem statement, I understood as yes we can have 2 --> 1 also

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in a onepass style

```
// all the "left" points of boats which ends in N
endingBoats = new Set // (e.g for boat [2,N] you store 2)

// all the "right" points of boats which start with 1
startingBoats = new Set // (e.g for boat [1, 3] your store 3)

for all boats:
  if boats does not start with 1 or end with N:
    continue

  // if boat starts with 1
  if boat[0] == 1:
    // check if there is a junction with a boat ending in N
    if endingBoats.has(boat[1]):
      return 'possible'
    // if not add the starting boat to candidates for junction
    startingBoats.add(boat[1])

  // if boat ends with N
  else if boat[1] == N:
    // check if there is a junction with a starting boat
    if startingBoats.has(boat[0]):
      return 'possible'
    // if not add the ending boat to candidates for junction
    endingBoats.add(boat[0])
return 'not possible'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you want to solve is a typycal problem on which you could apply dfs algorithm. Here is a first approach:

```
public class GrafDirLlistes {
ArrayList<Adj>[] elArray; //This is where we store the adjacent vertex to the current vertex

    boolean[] visitOrder;
    int[] path;

    public GrafDirLlistes(int numVert) {
        elArray = new ArrayList[numVert];
        for (int i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
            elArray[i] = new ArrayList();
        }
    }

public boolean existeixAresta(int v_orig, int v_desti) { //Method to check wheter an edge exists
        if (v_orig < 0 || v_orig >= elArray.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = v_orig; i < elArray[v_orig].size(); i++) {
            if (elArray[v_orig].get(i).vertDest == v_desti) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean afegirAresta(int v_orig, int v_dest, double pes) { // Method to add a new edge

        if (v_orig < 0 || v_orig >= elArray.length || v_dest < 0 || v_dest >= elArray.length) {
            return false;
        }

        if (existeixAresta(v_orig, v_dest)) {
            return false;
        }

        elArray[v_orig].add(new Adj(v_dest, pes));
        return true;
    }
```

Up there we create a graph, putting them in an array of arraylist. The function of the array is to see which are the adjacent vertex. For example, if we have a graph in which 0 points to 1, elArray[0] will have an ArrayList with only 1 element, the 1, that is the vertex 0 is pointing to.
The Adj class

```
public class Adj {

    public int vertDest;
    public double weight;

    public Adj(int v, double p) {
        vertDest = v;
        weight = p;
    }

}
```

Dfs method:

```
    public void dfs() {
        visitOrder = new boolean[elArray.length];
        path = new int[elArray.length];
        for (int v = 0; v < elArray.length; v++) {
            path[v] = -1;
        }

        for (int v = 0; v < elArray.length; v++) {
            if (!visitOrder[v]) {
                dfs(v);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dfs(int orig) {
        visitOrder[orig] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < elArray[i].size(); i++) {
            int v_dest = elArray[orig].get(i).vertDest;
            if (!visitOrder[v_dest]) {
                path[v_dest] = orig;
                dfs(v_dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when you finish dfs(), you only have to check path array, here will be stored if a path exists from x to y

Comment: DFS is overkill since he's only looking for paths of exact length 2.

Comment: In that case he can only check the adjacent edges contained in ```elArray[]``` and see if he can arrive to N in two steps

Comment: Thank you, but I did not understand where to start in your solution because my method signature starts with `String check(List<Integer> boat1, List<Integer> boat2, int N) `, Also variable or methods names are confusing, i mean `afegirAresta` , `existeixAresta` and `GrafDirLlistes`.  Can you please help me with these details.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. ```afegirAresta``` is the method I use to add a new edge, something like ```insertEdge```. ```existeixAresta``` is the method I use to check whether an edge exists from A to B. And ```GrafDirLlistes``` is the class name, it is named in that way because I want to represent a directed graph using lists. So when I saw your problem I thought that you could model the problem using graph theory

Comment: @Josep, Got it, can you please help me how to call these methods, because my entry point for this task is `String check(List<Integer> boat1, List<Integer> boat2, int N)`, for example boat1 with values 1,2,3,4 and boat 2 as values 3, 5 and N as 5.

Comment: What I see is that islands can be the vertex of our graph, and the boats are the way you can move from islands right?

Comment: Ok, so what you can do is, using the example you have posted, boat 1 goes from 1 to 2, so here you can add an edge to the graph that goes from 1 to 2, the second boat goes from 2 to 3. So you can see all the edges loking in your boat1 list an boat2. For the vertexes you only have to put N in the constructor of the class

Comment: @Josep, Im trying to insert edge using `afegirAresta(int v_orig, int v_dest, double pes)`, now I have nodes 1 and 2 for first boat which i can pass to v_orig and v_dest respectively, now what data should I pass to variable `pes` here?

Comment: Oh, right. ```pes``` is a variable that indicates the cost to go from ```v_orig``` to ```v_dest```. For problems like yours, 1, this is the value i use by default

Comment: @Josep, I have added details in my post under update section with an example, it should return true as per my requirement, but it is returning false. can you please check once, what I am missing here.

Comment: Yes, the fact is that ```existeixAresta``` only checks if exists an edge from A to B directly. So for your purpose, when you create the graph, then execute ```dfs``` and when ```dfs``` ends, you can see ```int[] path``` to check if you can arrive from your start vertex to the others. And other thing, the class is implemented from the way that the 0 is the first vertex, so when you put edges, take this into account

Answer (score 0):

The services are pairs of integers [from, to]. You need to first find the set of islands that can be reached from 1 in a single step. Then use all of those and build a new set of all that can be reached from any of them in one more step. You have some elements of this, but you're missing some ingredients.  Using `Map` and `Set` appropriately will make this computation very efficient. Key reasons to use `Set` are that it takes care of the issue where a given island can be reached by more than one path, and it's very quick to check whether the islands reachable in the second step contain the one you're interested in.

Here's one way to implement. Java streams simplify things.

```
class Length2Paths {
  private static final Set<Integer> NONE = (Set<Integer>) EMPTY_SET;

  static class Service {
    final int from, to;
    public Service(int from, int to) {
      this.from = from;
      this.to = to;
    }
  }

  static Set<Integer> getReachableIn2Steps(int from, List<Service> services) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> edges = 
        services.stream().collect(groupingBy(s -> s.from, mapping(s -> s.to,  toSet())));
    Set<Integer> reachableIn1Step = edges.getOrDefault(from, NONE);
    return reachableIn1Step.stream().flatMap(i -> edges.getOrDefault(i, NONE).stream()).collect(toSet());
  }

  static void printIfPossibleIn2StepsFrom1(int destination, List<Service> services) {
     System.out.println(getReachableIn2Steps(1, services).contains(destination) ? "POSSIBLE" : "IMPOSSIBLE");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Service [] services = { new Service(1, 2), new Service(2, 3) };
    printIfPossibleIn2StepsFrom1(3, Arrays.asList(services));
    printIfPossibleIn2StepsFrom1(2, Arrays.asList(services));
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
POSSIBLE
IMPOSSIBLE
```

Comment: Thank you, but looks like I have not given good example in my question, here is another example, each boat service can have multiple trips, means say `First boat services : 1 2 3 4`, means first boat I can travel to islands 1, 2, 3 and 4. Now lets say `Second boat services : 3 5`, using second boat I can go to islands 3 and 5. Now, number of islands N=5, so to travel from 1 to 5, I can use first boat 1->2->3 then in island 3 I can use second boat 3->5 to reach destination.